# Remove duplicates in a string. What am I missing?

Tags: c, string

Here is my try to remove duplicates of a string, and I have two questions:

```
void removeDuplicates(char *original_string)
{
    if(original_string == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    int len = strlen(original_string);
    if (len < 2) {
        return;
    }

    int tail = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j=0; j < tail; j++) {
            if (original_string[i] == original_string[j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == tail) {
            original_string[tail] = original_string[i];
            ++tail;
        }
    }
}
```

First: What am I doing wrong that I don't see? I have found this example in a book and I believe it makes sense.  Why are the duplicated characters not being deleted?

Second: When calling the function, if I do it with:

```
char duplicated[] = "aba";
removeDuplicates(duplicated);
```

I don't get an error. But if I do it with:

```
char *duplicated = "aba";
removeDuplicates(duplicated);
```

I get an `Bus error: 10` in run time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Comment: My question is not just about the error, but why the function is not working.

Comment: I don't see any such mention in your question. You said `when I do the first one I don't get error` and error for the second one. You haven't said anything about the whether it works or not. Do you expect us to compile and verify the functionality?

Comment: You don't see this? First: What am I doing wrong that I don't see? I have found this example in a book and I believe it makes sense. Why are the duplicated characters not being deleted? I don't expect you to do anything if you don't want to. I can't see why my program is not working and I am asking for help.

Comment: Nobody answered for what say now because your question never seemed to suggest  with that function itself. If so, you have to edit your question with that.

Answer (score 4):

```
char duplicated[] = "aba";
```

creates an **array** of `char`s, which is writable.

```
char *duplicated = "aba";
```

creates a string literal (which is unmodifiable) then the variable `duplicated` is assigned to the pointer to that string literal. Since your function tries to modify the string in-place, it invokes undefined behavior when attempting to write to a string literal, hence the crash.

Comment: But even declaring it as char duplicated[] = "aba"; I don't see the duplicated characters being deleted. Where is the mistake inside the function?

Comment: @HommerSmith Now that's another question. Have you tried debugging it? Also, what do you expect `original_string[i];` to do? It does nothing in itself. It's an expression statement without side effects whose value is immediately discarded - essentially a no-op.

Comment: It's in my original question... I ask two questions, the first one why is not working and the second one, why I get that error when declaring the string itself...

Answer (score 1):

`"..."` creates a **constant** chunk of memory holding your string.
You cannot modify it.

Therefore, modifying `original_string[tail]` is undefined behavior when called on a constant string.

Comment: `original_string[tail]` is not by itself undefined behavior. Otherwise, you couldn't use string literals in any (useful) way :)

Comment: Thanks for your question. Actually my question also included why is my method not working in removing duplicated characters. I fail to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

string literals are non-modifiable in C. it is undefined behaviour

So, `duplicated` has to be a local array:

or it has to be

```
char duplicated[] = "aba";
```

and not

```
char *duplicated = "aba";
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing is being removed

original_string[tail] = original_string[i]

that isn't removing anything, it's replacing